# How to upload a picture (file) to the server on android studio?

Tags: java, android, json

I need to upload a picture to the server. I've tried a lot of ways, but nothing comes out.

Here is the code I tried to use:

```
URL url2 = new URL(url_for_loading_image);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "token " + ClientToken);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                    JSONObject jsonParam2 = new JSONObject();
jsonParam2.put("photo", getActivity().getExternalCacheDir()+"/saved.jpg");
jsonParam2.put("collect", "ddd");
jsonParam2.put("user_comment", "dsdsds");
Log.i("JSON", jsonParam2.toString());
DataOutputStream os2 = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                    os.writeBytes(jsonParam2.toString());

                    os2.flush();
                    os2.close();
```

[loader screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjHw5.png)

How do I understand this part of the code from the site, is responsible for downloading?

```
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label ">
      Фото чека
  </label>    
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input name="photo"  type="file"  value="" >    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if any of the answers answer your doubts upvote and mark it as solved is extremly unpleasant create an account just for getting quick help and then leave without thanks tose who helped

Answer (score 0):

I created this function for this. You need send this RequestBody in your connection with server.

```
    return object : RequestBody() {

        override fun contentType() = return MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream")

        override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink?) {

            var bytes = ByteArray(length)

            while (file.available() > 0) {

                when (file) {
                    avaible >= length -> {
                        file.read(bytes, 0, length)
                        sink?.write(bytes)
                    } 
                    else -> {
                        bytes = ByteArray(file.available())
                        file.read(bytes, 0, file.available())
                        sink?.write(bytes)
                    }
                }   
            }    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do something invalid

JSON is a standard format for exchanging of **TEXT** information, or anything that can easily be converted to text.

As you can see in your own code:
`conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");`

This connection will send information of `json data`.

As you can imagine Photos, Videos and other tipes of media are not textual information and won't parsed by json api.

If i understood your print screen, the actual result of your code is that you are sending the **file path** and this is the expected behavior for your code...

Here is a code showing how to upload media files

```
/**
     * This constructor initializes a new HTTP POST request with content type
     * is set to multipart/form-data
     *
     * @param requestURL
     * @param charset
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);    // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
}
```

You will probably need to make two requests to the server or adapt the above code to send the json data into the multipart form

Answer (score 0):

This decision helped. Thank you all for your answers)

```
    public class FilesUploadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        // Конец строки
        private String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        // Два тире
        private String twoHyphens = "--";
        // Разделитель
        private String boundary =  "----WebKitFormBoundary9xFB2hiUhzqbBQ4M";

        // Переменные для считывания файла в оперативную память
        private int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        private byte[] buffer;
        private int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

        // Путь к файлу в памяти устройства
        private String filePath;

        // Адрес метода api для загрузки файла на сервер
        public static final String API_FILES_UPLOADING_PATH = "http://91.226.82.163:8000/api/v1/gallery/checklog/";

        // Ключ, под которым файл передается на сервер
        public static final String FORM_FILE_NAME = "photo";

        public FilesUploadingTask(String filePath) {
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Результат выполнения запроса, полученный от сервера
            String result = null;

            try {
                // Создание ссылки для отправки файла
                URL uploadUrl = new URL(API_FILES_UPLOADING_PATH);

                // Создание соединения для отправки файла
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uploadUrl.openConnection();

                // Разрешение ввода соединению
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                // Разрешение вывода соединению
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                // Отключение кеширования
                connection.setUseCaches(false);

                // Задание запросу типа POST
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // Задание необходимых свойств запросу
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "token " + ClientToken);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");

                // Создание потока для записи в соединение
                DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                // Формирование multipart контента

                // Начало контента
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                // Заголовок элемента формы
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                        FORM_FILE_NAME + "\"; filename=\"" + filePath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                // Тип данных элемента формы
                outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + lineEnd);
                // Конец заголовка
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // Поток для считывания файла в оперативную память
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // Считывание файла в оперативную память и запись его в соединение
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                // Конец элемента формы
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Получение ответа от сервера
                int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

                // Закрытие соединений и потоков
                fileInputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(connection.getResponseCode()));
                Log.i("MSG" , connection.getRequestMethod());
                // Считка ответа от сервера в зависимости от успеха
                if(serverResponseCode == 200) {
                    result = readStream(connection.getInputStream());
                } else {
                    result = readStream(connection.getErrorStream());
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }

        // Считка потока в строку
        public String readStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            return buffer.toString();
        }
    }
```